# Winform richtextbox Append Text for 24/7

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Here is my problem for the winform rich textbox, a program receive  message from car parking hardware by TCP/IP and I  display the Events in the winform richtextbox by

richtextbox.AppendText()

everything are working well except the program freeze within a day or two

Is there a better way to hand this?

Write to log file and bind it to the rich textbox?

Comment: You must make a limit to it. If more than your limit, the oldest record will be deleted. If you write it line by line, then ListBox is probably more suitable then RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before. 
Things to consider: Memory limits, HD (file size) and RAM (display)
If you want to implement this with WinForms and not use some existing logging code I think a ListView and a random access file of a fixed size with datetime and limited log string as a ring buffer would do. Or use e.g. SQLite (delete entries older than today - TimeSpan, insert new) and use a DataGridView (ideally derived and double buffered for smooth scrolling)..